# $\mu(A) = 0 \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\; \int_A f \,\, d\mu = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm ashamed to have to ask this question...

After poring over a few measure theory text books for the last couple of hours I still cannot figure out which theorem of "standard" measure theory, out of the bazillion theorems that these books give, justifies this stupefyingly obvious fact:

$$\mu(A) = 0 \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\; \int_A f \,\, d\mu = 0$$

Of course, I expect that some restrictions will need to be placed on the function $f$, and possibly on the measure $\mu$.  In fact, my interest in finding a formal statement of the theorem is to get some idea of how generally the above implication holds.

(I figure that the above implication *has* to be true, at least for most functions $f$ one could care about, if for no other reason that any theory of measure for which this wasn't the case would be pretty worthless.  Therefore, I expect the above implication would lie very close to the basic definitions of the theory.  But the books on measure theory I have on hand use such elaborate apparatus to develop the theory, that it is impossible for me to discern through all the machinery the really fundamental facts like this one.)

Comment: You should never be ashamed to ask a question.

Comment: It is not true if $\mu$ has negative and positive values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always true if the objects in question are well-defined (e.g. the integral of course needs to be well-defined), and if $\mu$ is a non-negative measure. The result comes from looking at the original definition of the integral. In particular, we originally define the integral by
$$ \mu(A) = \int_A 1 \, d\mu$$
Notice that by monotonicity, $B \subset A$ measurable implies $\mu(B) \le \mu(A)$, hence $\mu(B) = 0$. Now, we turn to how we define integrals on functions. First we approximate $f$ by a sequence of step functions
$$ f_n = \sum_{i} a_i 1_{B_i}$$
where $f_n \uparrow f$, and the $B_i$'s partition $A$. Then
$$ \int_A f_n \, d\mu = \sum_i a_i \int_{B_i} 1 \, d\mu = \sum_i a_i \mu(B_i) = 0$$
Since we *define* the integral of $f$ to be the limit of the integrals on $f_n$, then the integral of $f$ must also be $0$.

Comment: What if $\mu$ is not non-negative on $A$?

Comment: Then it's clearly false. Suppose $A = (0,1)$, and $\mu(0,1/2) = 1$ and $\mu(1/2,1) = -1$. Then $\mu(A) = 0$, but if $f = 1_{(1/2,1)}$ then $\int f \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_A f \,d\mu \leq \int_A\max(f)\,d\mu = \max(f)\int_A\,d\mu=\max(f)\mu(A)=0$$

Comment: This does not quite work as written: The function $f$ doesn't have to be bounded, and its supremum does not need to be a maximum. In fact, we want the integral to vanish even if $f$ is identically $+\infty$.

Comment: @Andres - This is assuming $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$ in the extended reals, as is common in measure theory.

Comment: Yes, and we could as well assume $f$ is a finite sum of step functions. My point is that all this scaffolding surrounding your computation may not be apparent to the person asking the question.